# Postgres : HikariPool-1 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, database-connection, hikaricp

I have a spring boot code setup designed to use Hikari Pool and Entity manager for querying PostgresSQL database.

Here are some things used for configuration:

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
   
   <persistence-unit name="EmF" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://url"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="some_password"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
         
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> <!-- DB Dialect -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->     
         
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
         <property name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" 
         value="com.thermofisher.hercules.data.repository.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"/>
         
      </properties>
      
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Repo class:

```
@Repository
public interface InputFileInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<InputFileInfo, Integer> {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmF");

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    
    
    default InputFileInfo saveAndPersist(InputFileInfo inputFileInfo) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        if(!transaction.isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        em.persist(inputFileInfo);
        transaction.commit();
        return inputFileInfo;
    }
```

When I run the application, it works fine and db operations are performed.
but if in between, connection to db gets lost on the system and when reconnected after sometime,
on performing db operations get the following error:

```
 2022-06-21 16:23:13.757  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@841b625 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
    2022-06-21 16:23:13.760  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@150fb29f (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
    2022-06-21 16:23:13.762  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@107ace85 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
    2022-06-21 16:23:13.765  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7f132fec (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
    2022-06-21 16:23:13.766  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3286a04f (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2022-06-21 16:23:16.047  WARN 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2022-06-21 16:23:16.048 ERROR 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
2022-06-21 16:23:16.066  INFO 8808 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.
```

Tried setting maxLifetime value through code :

```
spring.datasource.max-lifetime=600000
```

but cant find its timeout equivalent in postgres db settings

Any help on this is appreciated